# Join array elements with a string

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, implode

I want join array elements with a string (ex:`-`), i tried it with implode, but it don't work in my code.

How can fix it?

**PHP:**

```
<?php

   $count = 1;
   $ttttt = json_decode('["110,2"]');
   $nnnnn = array("110","1","2");
   $fffff = array('name','day','last');
   $Rtp = str_replace($nnnnn, $fffff, $ttttt, $count);
   echo implode(" - ", $Rtp); // This output is as: name,last

?>
```

**DEMO:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZNiBWy

Comment: That will work if you change your `json` string: `json_decode('["110","2"]');`

Comment: That does exactly what you programmed to do. What is your expected answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JSON is not valid the way you are expecting it, it generates only one value `110,2`.

Change it to `["110","2"]` and your implode should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array $ttttt = array(110, 2) .
You then replace all values in this array as follows 110 -> name, 2 -> last and 1 -> day, using str_replace.

So (110, 2) becomes ("name", "last")